# All type parameters depending on each other in functional dependencies

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies

Let's say I have a type class with *n* type parameters and I want any of them to uniquely determine all the other ones. Is it enough to make the dependencies form a cycle like in

```
class Foo a b c | a -> b, b -> c, c -> a
```

(linear) where there is a path from every parameter to every other one, or do I need to expand all possible paths like in

```
class Bar a b c | a -> b, a -> c, b -> a, b -> c, c -> a, c -> b
```

(quadratic)? Is there any observable difference between the two? And how about

```
class Baz a b c | a -> b c, b -> a c, c -> a b
```

Comment: I have no idea, but I really hope they are equivalent. I'd expect them to be.

Comment: I'd also like to know about `a -> b c, b -> a c, c -> a b` in relation...

Comment: @AndrásKovács Good point, I added it to the question.

Comment: I'd start by reading the original fundep paper: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/fundeps-esop2000.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Operationally, all of the above are equivalent:

First of all, `a -> b c` is quite literally the same thing as `a -> b, a -> c`.

Next, assume we got `Foo a b c => (a, b, c)`. Say, we realize that `a ~ A`. We find the `a -> b` fundep and scan through instances to find `b ~ B`. Again we find the `b -> c` fundep and realize `c ~ C`. Voila we got `(A, B, C)`.

If instead we had `Bar a b c => (a, b, c)` with `a ~ A`, we would've found `a -> b`, and `b ~ B`, however before finding `b -> c`, we would have found `a -> c`.

The only difference is which fundep arrows are used to infer the types. `a -> b, b -> c` and `a -> b, a -> c` can't produce different results.